# Dynamic AngularJS Meta description stopped showing up in Google results

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, meta-description, angular.js

```
<meta name="description" ng-bind="main.pageDescription" content="{{main.pageDescription}}">
```

This is how we used to have dynamic meta descriptions for different pages and it used to work well with Google before it stopped working last month. I have done some changes since then and have requested re-indexing but it's still the same. This is how Google results page looks now:
[image]

Some more info, if I view the page source (after the entire page has loaded), it still shows the angularJS code instead of compiled code.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Try ng-cloak for this. It should hide {{}} from google results.

Comment: This is a low quality answer. Can you explain this more? Assume the OP has little to no idea what you are talking about? For example, are you talking about a plug-in? Where can the OP find it? What does it do? Cheers!!